# Spark custom user log from aws EMR

Tags: apache-spark, logging, log4j, hadoop-yarn, emr

I'm running a spark job on EMR, (yarn, cluster-mode, transient - the cluster shuts down after the job is done) with debug mode turned on. all spark logs are uploaded to s3 as expected but I can't upload my own custom logs... 
Using log4j, I'm trying to write them to the folowing path acording to the spark doc `log4j.appender.algoLog.File=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/algoLog.log`

It seems like the variable is undefined. It tries to write directly to root. `/algoLog.log`.
If I'm writing it to other arbitrary location. It just doesn't appear on s3.
where should I write my own log files if I want EMR to upload them to s3 after the cluster shut down?

Comment: which Spark version are you using?

Comment: EMR version 5.5.0, Spark 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Log4J isn't set up to write to object stores; it's notion of filesystem is different.

you *may* be able to get YARN to do it with its log collection. See [How to keep YARN's log files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713587/how-to-keep-yarns-log-files)

Comment: I didn't try to give log4j s3 path. I tried to give it local path and I'm expecting that EMR will deliver those files into it's s3 logging bucket.

Comment: that's not anything I've played with; I do know YARN logging is designed to collect data from across the cluster and serve it up for viewing...though even there I don't know about s3 integration. sorry